# Laravel vue cannot access to relation data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have customer data which has hasOne relationship with address table.
Returned data format is like below.

```
{
  "customer_id": 1,
  "last_name": "Cruickshank",
  "first_name": "Pearl",
  "phone": "+4 921-008-8344",
  "email": "kristofer.kautzer@example.org",
  "order_id": null,
  "address_id": 66,
  "created_at": "2017-01-18 06:24:40",
  "updated_at": "2017-01-18 06:24:40",
  "deleted_at": null,
  "address": {
    "address_id": 1,
    "address_code": "RS-03549-9811",
    "address1": "14978 Effertz Turnpike Apt. 086",
    "address2": null,
    "city": "Susanaburgh",
    "province": "Illinois",
    "country": "PG",
    "postal_code": "03549-9811",
    "created_at": "2017-01-18 06:24:40",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-18 06:24:40"
  }
```

I got data using   `return $this->model->with(implode(',', $relation))->get();`

However, I cannot access any of data in address object.

Vue Code 
I throw city is undefined. However, I can access to address object data using chrome developer tool

```
<tr v-for="(customer, index) in customers">
     <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
     <td>{{getFullName(customer.first_name, customer.last_name)}}</td>
     <td>{{customer.phone}}</td>
     <td>{{customer.address.city}}</td>
</tr>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I tried `customer['address']['city']` as well.

I can access city when I get data as you see below.

```
getCustomerList () {
    axios.get('/api/customers')
       .then((res)=>{
          if(res.status === 200){
            //I can access city here but not in vue for loop ...
            console.log(res.data.customers[0].address.city)
            this.customers = res.data.customers
        }
    })
 },
```

Comment: is customers an array?

Comment: Its running code except  <td>{{customer.address.city}}</td>

Comment: Can you add you code of complete table.

Comment: try to output a `customer.address` instead. it helps you to detect how the `address` field organized and if it contains `city` field you'll see that. If you don't see it, i suppose problem in other place (no properly json conversion or data don't fetch from address table, etc)

Comment: also i get confused with this line `with(implode(',', $relation))` since each relation must be passed separatly to `with`, what your `relation` variable contains?

Comment: Either way does not work that code works. I also tried \Customers::with('address')->get(); which is right way i guess but still i cannot access might be vue's problem ? Please look at the bottom code that I newly added